# What methods exist to copy a gif to the clipboard and post it into other applications?

Tags: javascript, html, web, browser, webbrowser-control

I want to (programmatically) copy a gif to the clipboard such that I can paste it into modern chats like those of MS Teams or Discord.

There seem to be some "magic" happening in the backgroud when you do a `"right-click => copy"` that I haven't yet figured out.

For example, [this gif from reddit](https://i.redd.it/7w47exu6xshc1.gif) (also those of tenor) can be copied to both Teams and Discord.
[This from giphy](https://giphy.com/gifs/xbox-game-xbox-series-x-s-ZSDK6HMs2xLajnV0D9) works on Teams, but not on Discord. On Discord it's interpreted as a png object.
If I open a local gif file in the browser and copy it to the clipboard it's also interpreted as a png by Discord while nothing happens in Teams.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript) awesome stackoverflow comment explains how to use different APIs for clipboard access - with `ClipboardItem` still not being available in Firefox, and `document.execCommand('copy')` being deprecated.

However, with gifs there seems to be something extra needed to make it work. Does anyone know what?